# Should all ActionResult parameters be Nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please see the code below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Guid personID)
        {
            //do some work
        }
```

If a user browses to Details without passing a personID, then the application errors.  How do you handle this? Using Web Forms I would test that the parameter is not null at the beginning of the Page Load.  However, this is not possible with MVC.

Comment: Are you talking about your GET action or post action method ? You had shown the httppost action method in the question.

Comment: @Shyju, I am talking about both.  I am Trying to understand how to handle null parameters.

Comment: You can check if it is not null also in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your parameter nullable and check the the parameter to see if it is null or not before accessing it.

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? personID)
{
    if(personID!=null)
    {
        // use personID.Value 
    }
    else
    {

    }
    // to do : return something
}
```

For your http post action mehod also, you could do the same. But you need to have unique method signature for the http get and action method. So i assume you are having more parameters in your HttpPost action method.

Comment: Should nullable parameters always be used with ActionResult methods? Is there a scenario when they should not be used.

Comment: It depends. If your action method always get an param value, no need to use nullable param.For example if you have an action method which aceepts an id and return the details of that entity using the id. If it is not nullable type, MVC framework will show an error saying that the action method expects an id param. But if you make it nullable, the framework won't throw an error but you need to do the null checking in the action method and return an appropriate response.

Comment: If you let the framework handle it, then the user will be forwarded to the global event handler.  Is than an "acceptable" way of handling it? Thanks.

Comment: like i said, it depends. If other part of my application is always correctly sending the param value (when building the link to this action method), I would not worry too much. But on those days when i want to be extra perfect in what i do. I would handle it myself in the code so that i can show a nice view with a gracious message to the user ("The details you are looking for is not available")

Comment: The application will never use ActionMethods incorrectly.  I am specifically talking about a user typing in a web address without the correct parameters.

Comment: If you want the action method specific messages (nice message for the user) to be shown, use nullable param,do a null check in action method and return the view with message when it is null

Answer (score 0):

There is two way ,

Firstly use `Default` value parameter and check `Guid.Empty`

Secondly use `nulable` parameters and check for `HasValue` attribute

**Default parameter sample**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Guid personID = Guid.Empty)
{
    if(personID == Guid.Empty)
    {
        //do some work
    }
    else
    {
        // do some work
    }        
}
```

**Nulable parameters sample**

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? personID)
{

    if(personID.HasValue)
    {
        //do some work
    }
    else
    {
        // do some work
    }        
}
```

Comment: Should nullable parameters always be used with ActionResult methods? Is there ever a scenario when they should not be used?

Comment: There is no need to use it in order that the parameter will not be empty. Can you try this code ? I think that this code solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nullable parameter like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Guid? personID)
{
    if(personID != null)
    {
        //do some work
    }

}
```

So you could invoke the method using the right data type or passing in null as the argument.